# Rails - filter array having multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by, having

In a Rails controller I'm filtering an active record as follow:

```
x = [1,2]
y = [3,4]

z = x+y #[1,2,3,4]

@result = Model.where(attribute: z)
```

I need to `group_by` the collection by an attribute; following code works:

```
@filtered_result = @result.group_by(&:another_attribute)
```

Now I need to add a condition to the group by. I know I can use `.having` but I'm not able to write the following condition (pseudo code):

```
@filtered_result = @result.group_by(&:another_attribute)
                          .having(:attribute not in x and :attribute not in y)
```

Is there a way to get this working? Thanks

Comment: Did you try with `where`?

Comment: not really, can you kindly show me how to use .where with .group_by?

Comment: `group_by` is not the same as `group`, right?

Comment: In your case I think wolud be `.where.not(attribute: ['x', 'y'])`. Try with that and let me know if it worked.

Comment: @gabrielhilal Correct, they are not the same; `group_by` is a method from Ruby's `Enumerable` and `group` is only avilable in `ActiveRecord`. In fact, OP would be better using `group(:attribute)` instead.

Comment: I will try to refactor using `group` but I have a bunch of code depending on what I've already coded using `group_by` (so relying on the resulting hash). Any chance I can do what I need with an `.having` clause?

Comment: Can you post an example of an input with desired output? From what i understood, you should be able to use `where` just as @AlejandroMontilla recommended. And i don't think you could use `having` after a `group_by`, since the latter returns a `Hash` object.